# Automatically install driver in delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, driver

How can i install a driver using delphi ?

I have a device that i connect through the usb port and needs some drivers to be installed i can do this by installing it manually but how can i do this automatically ?
How does windows know that that driver is for that device ?

Comment: You normally install drivers with an install program. Where does Delphi come into it?

Comment: @David The device is a custom made one i have the raw drivers and i want to make an install program to install those drivers!In delphi of course!

Comment: Why write an installer in Delphi? That's not the best way in general. Use a tool for creating install packages rather than a tool for creating applications.er than a tool for creating applications.

Comment: @David i want a simple click and go installer...I think is very easy what i want

Comment: So what exactly is the difficulty if it is very easy? I believe that an install tool will guide you through all the steps needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this

```
>  ShellAPI;
> 
> function InstallINF(const PathName: string; hParent: HWND): Boolean;
> var    instance: HINST; begin    instance := ShellExecute(hParent,
>      PChar('open'),
>      PChar('rundll32.exe'),
>      PChar('setupapi,InstallHinfSection
>            DefaultInstall 132 ' + PathName),
>      nil,
>      SW_HIDE) ;
> 
>    Result := instance > 32; end;
```

I will test it and come back with a result

Comment: FWIW, the PChar casts around the pure literals, like 'open' and 'rundll32.exe' are not needed.

Comment: I still think using InnoSetup is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi isn't the natural choice for writing an installer. Instead you should use one of the many products dedicated to creating install packages, e.g.

- InstallShield
- InstallAware
- NSIS
- WiX
- Wise
- InnoSetup
- etc.

Of these InnoSetup uses a Pascal variant as its scripting language and so is a very popular choice amongst Delphi developers.

Comment: InnoSetup itself is written in Delphi.I told you i don't want nothing fancy just install a driver...

Comment: InnoSetup creates Windows installers. Nothing "fancy" but precisely what you need.

Comment: Sometimes installing a driver might or should be postponed. Knowing how to code the driver install process is different than knowing what installer products are available.

Comment: @too could you elaborate on this, perhaps in an answer. It sounds as though you have some good information and knowledge to share.

Answer (score 0):

Study the source code of InnoSetup. Its available for download at the InnoSetup home page.
If that's not enough, there are numerous examples of scripts and helper functions available for InnoSetup with tons of information. 
We made an installer the same way 15 years ago and it's still in operation without changes.